# DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] Previously Authenticated

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am developing a soap web service using https channel. The user credentials and roles are defined in a property file.

```
<security:http  authentication-manager-ref="basicauthenticationManager" pattern="/webservice" entry-point-ref="basicAuthEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/views/ws404.html" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/webservice/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"  requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/webservice" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>
```

```
<security:authentication-manager id="basicauthenticationManager">
   <security:authentication-provider >
        <security:user-service properties="classpath:users.properties">             
        </security:user-service>        
   </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When I call the web service only once I dont get any DEBUG error message but when called in a loop get the following error

---

### ERROR

**11:53:13,721 DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authenti
cation.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90556c3e: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticate
d: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddre
ss: 10.11.160.39; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
11:53:13,722 DEBUG [AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionV
oter@19c0b5c, returned: -1
11:53:13,723 DEBUG [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentic
ation entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(Abstract
SecurityInterceptor.java:205)**

The server processes the request successfully, how can I suppress or avoid this DEBUG message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Spring Security FAQ](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html5/#appendix-faq-anon-access-denied), this isn't an error, it's logged at debug level.

If you want to suppress it just disable debug-level logging for the Spring Security package. For example, if you are using logback for logging (as used in the Spring Security sample applications, change `DEBUG` to `INFO` on [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.10.RELEASE/samples/tutorial-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml#L8).